# How to automatically update a field when creating another record in different models?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have two models that look like this:

```
class TeamMember(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET(get_default_team_member), 
                verbose_name='Member Name', related_name="team_members")
    team = models.ManyToManyField('Team', verbose_name='Team Name', 
            related_name="team_members", blank=False, default=team_id)
    shift = models.ForeignKey(Shift, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
... 
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(TeamMember, blank=True, related_name="members")

`
```

The users use the admin panel to add new members. When adding a new member, I want to automatically add the member to the associated team.

For example, when adding John, it is required to assign a team to him(blank=False), and the team is from what we have in the Team model. Then how do I update the members in the Team model to add John to one of the teams accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
form = TeamMemberForm()
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save()
    team = Team.objects.create(name="John")
    instance.members.add(team)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The use case of these models is usually in the admin panel so there is nowhere to add a form like this. I should be clear on that in the post

Comment: You can use this lines of codes in the 
team = Team.objects.create(name="John")
instance.members.add(team)

in TeamMember post_save signal as well as.

Comment: @receiver(post_save, sender=TeamMember)
def save_team(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    your code here

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    is_activate = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def create_auto_slug(self):
        self.slug = slugify(f'{self.name}-{self.pk}')

    def model2save(self):
        MyModel2.objects.create(**your_data)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.create_auto_slug()
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.model2save()
```

other method - [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/)